# surf3Dwrite with CUDA 5

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to compile a kernel in CUDA 5 that uses Surface Objects. However, this doesn't seem to work exactly as described in the manual.

```
__global__ void kernel_reset(cudaSurfaceObject_t surf)
{
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int z = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
    surf3Dwrite(0u, surf, x * sizeof(unsigned int), y, z, cudaBoundaryModeTrap);
}
```

This fails to compile with:

```
error : no instance of overloaded function "surf3Dwrite" matches the argument list
```

The overload I want is listed in surface_indirect_functions.h as:

```
static __forceinline__ __device__ void surf3Dwrite(unsigned int data, cudaSurfaceObject_t surfObject, int x, int y, int z, cudaSurfaceBoundaryMode boundaryMode = cudaBoundaryModeTrap)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Simple question: have you all includes correct?

Comment: I discovered the cause of this problem. The code was ok - the problem was in the compiler arguments.

Since Texture Objects require a compute capability of 2.0 or higher, I had to change the NVCC compiler settings from "compute_10,sm_10" to "compute_20,sm_20". 

This fixed the issue. Thanks

Comment: Since you answer your question you can close it :)

Comment: @TobySharp please post your answer and accept it (may have to wait a day to accept your own answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the cause of this problem.

The code was ok - the problem was in the compiler arguments: Since Texture Objects require a compute capability of 2.0 or higher, I had to change the NVCC compiler settings from "compute_10,sm_10" to "compute_20,sm_20". This fixed the issue.

Thanks.